# Cycle of length

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

I'm learning permutations and came upon this question which made me freeze. So to say it in my own words, it asks that how many permutations in $S_n$ do not have a cycle of length one in their disjoint cycle notation. My guess at it would be just one but I don't know how to show it.

Comment: Have you tried writing down all the permutations of $S_3$ as products of disjoint cycles?

Comment: Tough problem, if you are meeting it fresh. Look at the wikipedia article on **Derangements.**

Comment: @AndréNicolas I looked at Derangments but it confused me further. I  can see the connection to a certain limit but Im not able to solve for this problem.

Comment: @user66345 Like this? $(a,b,c)=(a,c),(a,b)$